# .Context.tt Error when splitting Entities and POCO Objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, poco

I followed this tutorial http://www.allenconway.net/2013/01/separating-entity-framework-poco.html for splitting my Entities and POCO into seperate projects. But every single time I get an error in my .context.tt for my DbSet Objects:

```
Error   3   The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have changed the namespace for the .context.tt
I tried adding a using statement as well.
I also added a reference as well.

any idea how I can resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had referenced the projects backwards. Make sure you have the correct references.